# mvc default validation on numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

I have a numeric property on my model and i am using editorfor on my razor view with it. The field is not mandatory but the default validation makes the user enter a value because it wont accept an empty string for a number. I have ended up changing the model property to a string and then putting my own custom validation attribute on the property. This cant possibly be the correct way of getting what i want....can it??

```
[NonMandatoryDoubleValidation("Latitude")]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a nullable double: `double?`. That way your variable will accept empty string or null value as well as double values. However, you'll need to check if it's empty each time you use it with `Latitude.HasValue` and use `Latitude.Value` to get its value.

Comment: thanks - someone else i know has pointed me towards "data annotation extensions"

Answer (score 0):

How about a nullable double:

```
[Required]
public double? Latitude { get; set; }
```